# getting past event by participant

Tags: civievent, drupal-views, registration

I am setting up views loading civicrm events and loaded the uid of user, and wanted to match the UID with the event he/she is registered from,

in views, I can not connect to participants through anywhere, when I tried loading relations ships :

```
    <select class="ctools-master-dependent form-select ctools-dependent-processed" id="edit-group" name="group">
<option value="all">- All -</option>
<option value="civicrm-custom--contact-person">CiviCRM Custom: Contact Person</option>
<option value="civicrm-custom--moderator">CiviCRM Custom: Moderator</option>
<option value="civicrm-custom--panelist">CiviCRM Custom: Panelist</option>
<option value="civicrm-custom--workgroup">CiviCRM Custom: Workgroup</option>
<option value="civicrm-events">CiviCRM Events</option><option value="civicrm-phone-details">CiviCRM Phone Details</option>
<option value="civicrm-price-set-entities">CiviCRM Price Set Entities</option></select>
```

I tried using the civicrm phone details but when connecting the civicrm participants its not loading anything

anywhere to connect it?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to show 'my events' you can create a View based on civicrm participants, then use Relationship to pull in "CiviCRM Contacts: Drupal ID", then set a views Filter to 'user: current = yes". Done.

But if i misunderstood then pls clarify the outcome you want and in what context.

Comment: you are correct using this method gets the participants info I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Woah! Hold your horses!

UID is a Drupal ID! CiviCRM has contact IDs - the two aren't the same. You can find the pairing in the civicrm_uf_match table :)

Comment: do I need to use custom pull in views?